# Stats data scheme

Tags: mongodb, statistics, aggregation-framework

I'm going to collect a lot of stats data and count some values (like popularity). After that I need to display it as graph. I read [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) and my task looks pretty simple: create document per each day, store data as described in article. When I'll need to get most popular values for last 3 days I'll just use aggregation framework. Very simple....

But how can I get most popular values for last 24 hours in this case? I can filter documents for last 2 days but it != last 24 hours...

Is it possible to be flexible in date range with scheme described above?

**added:**

Following data structure uses single document to store information for the whole day:

```
{
    _id: "20101010/site-1/apache_pb.gif",
    metadata: {
        date: ISODate("2000-10-10T00:00:00Z"),
        site: "site-1",
        page: "/apache_pb.gif" },
    daily: 5468426,
    hourly: {
        "0": 227850,
        "1": 210231,
        ...
        "23": 20457 },
    minute: {
        "0": 3612,
        "1": 3241,
        ...
        "1439": 2819 }
}
```

Using aggregation framework I can select documents for last week (max 7), group by `metadata.site` and sum `daily` to get total visits by site. Is it possible to count total visits by site for last 24 hours with the scheme suggested above?

(there is a simple way to create `by hour` documents but I don't wanna do it because of performance reasons)

Comment: Please make your question more specific with code and schema + data examples. You can't expect people read a lengthy article to answer your question. ;)

Comment: fixed. I hope it's enough to understand my question

Answer (score 0):

You can still keep the same schema and all you need to do is to change the query.

Instead of doing `sum` on `daily` you just need to *project* `daily` in your results. Because you don't have to do any aggregations in this case you don't even have to use aggregation framework and your query becomes quite simple. Here is an example of a new query that returns count only:

```
db.coll.find({date: {$gt: ISODate("2000-10-10T00:00:00Z"),
                     $lt: ISODate("2000-10-11T00:00:00Z")}},
             {"daily": 1, "_id": 0});
```

Comment: it will return total visits for current day... but it isn't equals to last 24 hours. Suppose that current time is `12:23pm`. So I need to collect data from `12:24pm` Yestarday till now.